# Resize Form based on ElementHost size

Tags: wpf, winforms, elementhost

I have a `Form(winform)` and it contains `Elementhost`. During run time, i am hosting my WPF Usercontrols to this `elementhost`. I have used `AutoSize = True` for elementhost.

`Elementhost` resizes itself basedon WPF Usercontrol size. But How to resize my form based my ElementHost's size.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer:

After setting the ElementHost.Child to WPF User control. I will following function:

```
public System.Windows.Size GetElementPixelSize(UIElement element) 
    { 
        Matrix transformToDevice; 
        var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(element);
        if (source != null)
            transformToDevice = source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
        else     
            using (var Hwndsource = new HwndSource(new HwndSourceParameters()))
                transformToDevice = Hwndsource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;


        if (element.DesiredSize == new System.Windows.Size()) 
            element.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity)); 

        return (System.Windows.Size)transformToDevice.Transform((Vector)element.DesiredSize); 
    }
```

**Original Method posted at: [How do I convert a WPF size to physical pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286175/how-do-i-convert-a-wpf-size-to-physical-pixels)**

Now I set the client size from new Size.

Comment: When you set you set the client size from the new size you mean: ElementHost.ClientSize = GetElementPixelSize(wpfUserControl) ? You are returning System.Windows.Size and ElementHost.ClientSize is of type System.Drawing.Size, so how do you perform such assignment?

Answer (score 0):

sory, but isn't it possible to subscribe to [size changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.resize%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and update the host form?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I did the same. I have override the Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint) and I have also triggering an event in this method. My Host Form subscribed to this event and gets notification and update the Form. But I think it is a FIX not a solution. What do you say?

Comment: @341184 could you give some code to look. As far for now I don't see prettier solution.

Comment: finally I got the answer and I have posted the same. Original Method posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286175/how-do-i-convert-a-wpf-size-to-physical-pixels

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this, but not sure about output.It worked in WPF Desktop application.
what you have to do is set the height and width to NAN (not a number)

```
this.Width = double.NaN;
this.Height = double.NaN;
```

Comment: finally I got the answer and I have posted the same. Original Method posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286175/how-do-i-convert-a-wpf-size-to-physical-pixels

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting autosize set:

```
 this.elementHost1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I come by it often, so it's still relevant, so here is my solution:

What I do is:

a. When I want WPF view to match (dock) window size:

```
ElementHost eh = new ElementHost();
eh.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Dock;
eh.AutoSize = true;
eh.Child = wpfView;
eh.CreateControl();
this.Controls.Add(eh);
this.AutoSize = false;
```

NOTE: You can set eh min size to have scrollbars, if form too small.

b: When I want the host Form to match the WPF View:

```
ElementHost eh = new ElementHost();
eh.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.None;
eh.AutoSize = true;
eh.Child = wpfView;
eh.CreateControl();
this.Controls.Add(eh);
this.AutoSize = true;
this.AutoSizeMode=AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
```