# WPF Interop Control renders black when .Net Framework is changed from 3.5 to 4.5

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms-interop, wpf-interop

I have an interop question about embedding WinForms controls into a WPF application and differences in the .Net framework versions.

The following should show a transparent wpf control (red box) over a WebBrowser control and works as expected when using .Net 3.5:

[image]

... but after compilation with .Net 4.5 the following occurs.

[image]

Everything works again when switching back to .Net 3.5

The following Code works for WPF with Win32 using .Net 3.0 up to .Net 3.5 but not with .Net 4.0/4.5:

Win32HostRenderer.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFInterop.Interop.Win32HostRenderer"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
      <Image Name="_interopRenderer" Stretch="None"/>    
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Win32HostRenderer.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;

using Winforms = System.Windows.Forms;
using GDI = System.Drawing;

using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace WPFInterop.Interop
{
    public partial class Win32HostRenderer : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, uint nFlags);


    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory")]
    private static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr Destination, IntPtr Source, int Length);

    private DispatcherTimer     _rendererTimer;
    private int                 _rendererInterval = 33;

    private InteropForm         _interopForm;
    private Winforms.Control    _winformControl;

    private BitmapSource        _bitmapSource;
    private BitmapBuffer        _bitmapSourceBuffer;

    private GDI.Bitmap          _gdiBitmap;
    private GDI.Graphics        _gdiBitmapGraphics;
    private IntPtr              _hGDIBitmap;


    public Win32HostRenderer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitializeInteropForm()
    {
        if (_winformControl == null) return;

        if (_interopForm != null)
        {
            TearDownInteropForm();
        }

        _interopForm = new InteropForm();
        _interopForm.Opacity = 0.01;
        _interopForm.Controls.Add(_winformControl);
        _interopForm.Width = _winformControl.Width;
        _interopForm.Height = _winformControl.Height;
    }

    private void TearDownInteropForm()
    {
        if (_interopForm == null) return;
        _interopForm.Hide();
        _interopForm.Close();
        _interopForm.Dispose();
        _interopForm = null;
    }

    private void InitializeRendererTimer()
    {
        TearDownRenderTimer();

        _rendererTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _rendererTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, _rendererInterval);
        _rendererTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(_rendererTimer_Tick);
        _rendererTimer.Start();
    }

    void _rendererTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RenderWinformControl();
    }

    private void TearDownRenderTimer()
    {
        if (_rendererTimer == null) return;

        _rendererTimer.IsEnabled = false;

    }
    private void RegisterEventHandlers()
    {
        Window currentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
        currentWindow.LocationChanged += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PositionInteropFormOverRender();
        });


        currentWindow.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PositionInteropFormOverRender();
        });

        currentWindow.Deactivated += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //_interopForm.Opacity = 0;
        });

        currentWindow.Activated += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // _interopForm.Opacity = 0.01;
        });

        currentWindow.StateChanged += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PositionInteropFormOverRender();
        });


        _interopRenderer.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PositionInteropFormOverRender();
        });
    }



    private void PositionInteropFormOverRender()
    {
        if (_interopForm == null) return;
        Window currentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);

        Point interopRenderScreenPoint = _interopRenderer.PointToScreen(new Point());

        _interopForm.Left = (int)interopRenderScreenPoint.X;
        _interopForm.Top = (int)interopRenderScreenPoint.Y;

        int width = 0;

        if ((int)_interopRenderer.ActualWidth > (int)currentWindow.Width)
        {
            width = (int)currentWindow.Width;
        }
        else
        {
            width = (int)_interopRenderer.ActualWidth;
        }

        if ((int)currentWindow.Width < width) 
                        width = (int)currentWindow.Width;

        _interopForm.Width = width;
    }

    private void InitializeBitmap()
    {
        if (_bitmapSource == null)
        {
            TearDownBitmap();
        }

        int interopRenderWidth = _winformControl.Width;
        int interopRenderHeight = _winformControl.Height;
        int bytesPerPixel = 4;

        int totalPixels = interopRenderWidth * interopRenderHeight * bytesPerPixel;

        byte[] dummyPixels = new byte[totalPixels];

        _bitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(interopRenderWidth, 
                                    interopRenderHeight, 
                                    96, 
                                    96, 
                                    PixelFormats.Bgr32, 
                                    null,
                                    dummyPixels,
                                    interopRenderWidth * bytesPerPixel);

        _interopRenderer.Source = _bitmapSource;

        _bitmapSourceBuffer = new BitmapBuffer(_bitmapSource);

        _gdiBitmap = new GDI.Bitmap(_winformControl.Width,
                                    _winformControl.Height, 
                                    GDI.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

        _hGDIBitmap = _gdiBitmap.GetHbitmap();

        _gdiBitmapGraphics = GDI.Graphics.FromImage(_gdiBitmap);
    }

    private void TearDownBitmap()
    {
        _bitmapSource = null;
        _bitmapSourceBuffer = null;

        if (_gdiBitmap != null)
        {
            _gdiBitmap.Dispose();
        }

        if (_gdiBitmapGraphics != null)
        {
            _gdiBitmapGraphics.Dispose();
        }

        if (_hGDIBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            DeleteObject(_hGDIBitmap);
        }
    }

    private void InitializeWinformControl()
    {
        InitializeInteropForm();
        InitializeBitmap();
        RegisterEventHandlers();

        PositionInteropFormOverRender();
        _interopForm.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;


        _interopForm.Show();
        InitializeRendererTimer();

    }

    public Winforms.Control Child
    {
        get { return _winformControl; }
        set
        {
            _winformControl = value;
            InitializeWinformControl();
        }
    }

    private void RenderWinformControl()
    {
        PaintWinformControl(_gdiBitmapGraphics, _winformControl);

        GDI.Rectangle lockRectangle = new GDI.Rectangle(0, 
                                                        0, 
                                                        _gdiBitmap.Width, 
                                                        _gdiBitmap.Height);

        GDI.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = _gdiBitmap.LockBits(lockRectangle, 
                                                        GDI.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, 
                                                        GDI.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        System.IntPtr bmpScan0 = bmpData.Scan0;

        CopyMemory(_bitmapSourceBuffer.BufferPointer, 
                   bmpScan0,
                   (int)_bitmapSourceBuffer.BufferSize);

        _gdiBitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        _interopRenderer.InvalidateVisual(); 
    }

    private void PaintWinformControl(GDI.Graphics graphics, Winforms.Control control)
    { 
        IntPtr hWnd = control.Handle;
        IntPtr hDC = graphics.GetHdc();

        PrintWindow(hWnd, hDC, 0);

        graphics.ReleaseHdc(hDC);
        }
    }
}
```

BitmapBuffer.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using System.Windows;

using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WPFInterop
{
    class BitmapBuffer
    {
        private BitmapSource _bitmapImage = null;

        private object _wicImageHandle = null;

        private object _wicImageLock = null;

        private uint _bufferSize = 0;

        private IntPtr _bufferPointer = IntPtr.Zero;

        private uint _stride = 0;

        private int _width;

        private int _height;

        public BitmapBuffer(BitmapSource Image)
        {
            //Keep reference to our bitmap image
            _bitmapImage = Image;

            //Get around the STA deal
            _bitmapImage.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
            {
                //Cache our width and height
                _width = _bitmapImage.PixelWidth;
                _height = _bitmapImage.PixelHeight;
                return null;
            }), null);

            //Retrieve and store our WIC handle to the bitmap
            SetWICHandle();

            //Set the buffer pointer
            SetBufferInfo();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The pointer to the BitmapImage's native buffer
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr BufferPointer
        {
            get
            {
                //Set the buffer pointer
                SetBufferInfo();
                return _bufferPointer;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The size of BitmapImage's native buffer
        /// </summary>
        public uint BufferSize
        {
            get { return _bufferSize; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The stride of BitmapImage's native buffer
        /// </summary>
        public uint Stride
        {
            get { return _stride; }
        }

        private void SetBufferInfo()
        {
            int hr = 0;

            //Get the internal nested class that holds some of the native functions for WIC
            Type wicBitmapNativeMethodsClass = Type.GetType("MS.Win32.PresentationCore.UnsafeNativeMethods+WICBitmap, PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");

            //Get the methods of all the static methods in the class
            MethodInfo[] info = wicBitmapNativeMethodsClass.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            //This method looks good
            MethodInfo lockmethod = info[0];

            //The rectangle of the buffer we are
            //going to request
            Int32Rect rect = new Int32Rect();

            rect.Width = _width;
            rect.Height = _height;

            //Populate the arguments to pass to the function
            object[] args = new object[] { _wicImageHandle, rect, 2, _wicImageHandle };

            //Execute our static Lock() method
            hr = (int)lockmethod.Invoke(null, args);

            //argument[3] is our "out" pointer to the lock handle
            //it is set by our last method invoke call
            _wicImageLock = args[3];

            //Get the internal nested class that holds some of the
            //other native functions for WIC
            Type wicLockMethodsClass = Type.GetType("MS.Win32.PresentationCore.UnsafeNativeMethods+WICBitmapLock, PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");

            //Get all the native methods into our array
            MethodInfo[] lockMethods = wicLockMethodsClass.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            //Our method to get the stride value of the image
            MethodInfo getStrideMethod = lockMethods[0];

            //Fill in our arguments
            args = new object[] { _wicImageLock, _stride };

            //Execute the stride method
            getStrideMethod.Invoke(null, args);

            //Grab out or byref value for the stride
            _stride = (uint)args[1];

            //This one looks perty...
            //This function will return to us 
            //the buffer pointer and size
            MethodInfo getBufferMethod = lockMethods[1];

            //Fill in our arguments
            args = new object[] { _wicImageLock, _bufferSize, _bufferPointer };

            //Run our method
            hr = (int)getBufferMethod.Invoke(null, args);

            _bufferSize = (uint)args[1];
            _bufferPointer = (IntPtr)args[2];

            DisposeLockHandle();
        }

        private void DisposeLockHandle()
        {
            MethodInfo close = _wicImageLock.GetType().GetMethod("Close");
            MethodInfo dispose = _wicImageLock.GetType().GetMethod("Dispose");

            close.Invoke(_wicImageLock, null);
            dispose.Invoke(_wicImageLock, null);
        }

        private void SetWICHandle()
        {
            //Get the type of bitmap image
            Type bmpType = typeof(BitmapSource);

            //Use reflection to get the private property WicSourceHandle
            FieldInfo fInfo = bmpType.GetField("_wicSource",
                                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            //Retrieve the WIC handle from our BitmapImage instance
            _wicImageHandle = fInfo.GetValue(_bitmapImage);
        }

    }
}
```

The InteropForm is just a derived System.Windows.Forms.Form and has no special magic.

Integration into WPF-Page is simple:

```
  <interop:Win32HostRenderer x:Name="_host" Grid.Row="0">
  </interop:Win32HostRenderer>
```

And after window Loaded event:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
    browser.Navigate("http://www.youtube.com");
    browser.Width = 700;
    browser.Height = 500;

    _host.Child = browser;
```

(code parts from Jeremiah Morrill, see [this blog](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/20/Composited-Win32-in-WPF-prototype-source-code.aspx) for more info)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, your first problem is with this bit of code:

```
    //Get the methods of all the static methods in the class
    MethodInfo[] info = wicBitmapNativeMethodsClass.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    //This method looks good
    MethodInfo lockmethod = info[0];
```

In .Net 4, the "Lock" method is at index 1 (probably because a new "static" method has been added)...so your reflection code is using the wrong one.

[image]

Instead you can just use this to get it by name (suggest altering your other `GetMethods` to `GetMethod`):

```
MethodInfo lockmethod = wicBitmapNativeMethodsClass.GetMethod("Lock", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Here it is working (in .NET 4)...I made it fill the client space...as I didn't have your full source code...alter as necessary to do your visual reflection, etc:

[image]

The changes I made were:

```
MethodInfo lockmethod = wicBitmapNativeMethodsClass.GetMethod("Lock", BindingFlags.Static |   BindingFlags.NonPublic);

private void PositionInteropFormOverRender()
{
    if (_interopForm == null) return;
    Window currentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);

    FrameworkElement firstchild = this.Content as FrameworkElement;
    if (firstchild != null)
    {
        Point interopRenderScreenPoint = currentWindow.PointToScreen(new Point());

        _interopForm.Left = (int)interopRenderScreenPoint.X;
        _interopForm.Top = (int)interopRenderScreenPoint.Y;

        _interopForm.Width = (int)firstchild.RenderSize.Width;
        _interopForm.Height = (int)firstchild.RenderSize.Height;
    }
}

private void _host_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
    browser.Navigate("http://www.youtube.com");
    browser.Width = 700;
    browser.Height = 500;
    browser.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

    _host.Child = browser;
}

private void InitializeInteropForm()
{
    if (_winformControl == null) return;

    if (_interopForm != null)
    {
        TearDownInteropForm();
    }

    _interopForm = new InteropForm();
    _interopForm.Opacity = 0.5;
    _interopForm.Controls.Add(_winformControl);
    _interopForm.Width = _winformControl.Width;
    _interopForm.Height = _winformControl.Height;
}
```

There are other things you need to fix/do/be aware of i.e.:

- when the screen DPI is not 96dpi, you will have to convert the RenderSize.Width/Height values accordingly (see: [How do I convert a WPF size to physical pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286175/how-do-i-convert-a-wpf-size-to-physical-pixels))
- your "browser" window is hidden in the z-order when you drag the main Window...you just need to bring it back to the front.

Comment: hmm, seems to me it is always the first one at 3.5 and 4.5

Comment: Results from Reflection are not guaranteed to be sorted in any order: _The GetMethods method does not return methods in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which methods are returned, because that order varies._ [http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/4d848zkb(v=vs.110).aspx] Same should be kept in mind for other reflection methods (GetFields etc).